# asp:DataList - Column Border

Tags: asp.net, css

I am really stuck on this one. This datalist is listing rows with border.  However, the columns doesn't have border. I couldn't figure out how to display a border line between columns (harder than I thought, not like HTML table/row format).

Note that, I already tried `<td style='width: 200px; border:1px solid black;'>`, but it is not working.

Please help, Thanks.

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyList"  runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyField="Company"
    UseAccessibleHeader="true"
    CssClass="books"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
    AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="alternating" 
    GridLines="Both"
    CellPadding="1"
    CellSpacing="3"
    ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" 
    >                
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="table1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px;">        
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="+" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'
                OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"  
                Font-Underline="false" 

                ></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
              <td style="width: 300px;"><%#Eval("Row")%>
              <td style="width: 300px"><%#Eval("Company")%>
        </tr>    
        </table>     

              <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding-left:50px;">
                <asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <tr>
                          <td><%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
                          <td><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>                        
                       </tr>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:DataList>
           </asp:Panel>

    </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>                
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: there are 2 td tags that were not closed

Comment: you need to use CSS to overwrite styles